# Why can't ghci find the Monad instance for EIther b

Tags: haskell, typeclass

So, it's been a few months and  I'm a bit rusty, but I seem to remember `Either b` being a `Monad`

```
Prelude Control.Monad Data.Either> return "Hello" :: Either String String

<interactive>:0:1:                                                       
    No instance for (Monad (Either String))                              
      arising from a use of `return'                                     
    Possible fix:                                                        
      add an instance declaration for (Monad (Either String))            
    In the expression: return "Hello" :: Either String String            
    In an equation for `it':                                             
        it = return "Hello" :: Either String String                      
Prelude> Right "Hi" == return "Hi"                                    

<interactive>:0:15:                                                   
    No instance for (Monad (Either a0))                               
      arising from a use of `return'                                  
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monad (Either a0)) 
    In the second argument of `(==)', namely `return "Hi"'            
    In the expression: Right "Hi" == return "Hi"                      
    In an equation for `it': it = Right "Hi" == return "Hi"
```

So I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. I'm using GHC 7.2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import `Control.Monad.Trans.Error` or `Control.Monad.Error`.
`Either a` monad instances are usually used in error handlings.

```
> return "Hello" :: (Either String String)
Right "Hello"
```

Answer (score 11):

As of [`base-4.6.0.0`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.0), the `Monad` and `Functor` instances for `Either e` are defined in `Data.Either` and automatically available from the `Prelude`.

Previously, in [`base-4.3.*`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.0.0) to [`base-4.5*`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0), the instance was defined in `Control.Monad.Instances` and not automatically available. Before that, and in part concurrently with it, there was an

```
instance Error e => Monad (Either e) where
    ...
```

defined in [`Control.Monad.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.1.1/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Error.html) of [`mtl-1.*`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.1.1), and in [`Control.Monad.Trans.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.1.0.0/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html) from the [`transformers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers) package. These modules still provide the instance (now without the `Error` constraint) conditionally, if they are used with a `base < 4.3`.